# What's the mistake in $\sin(\frac{a}{2})=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1\pm \cos(a)}{2}}$?

Tags: trigonometry, fake-proofs

When I was encountered with the formula of $\sin(\frac{a}{2})$, I tried to derive it. First, I tried from the formula of $\cos(2a)$ and I successfully did that but after a while I was curious about if that can be derived from sine's double angle formula and for which I came up with the equation above in the title, totally wrong, as that is kind of combination of sine's and cosine's half angle formula. Here is the derivation:-
$$\sin(2a)=2\sin(a)\cos(a)$$ 
or, $$\sin(a)=2\sin(\frac{a}{2})\cos(\frac{a}{2}) $$
or, $$\sin^2(a)=4\sin^2(\frac{a}{2})(1-\sin^2(\frac{a}{2})) $$
or, $$\sin^4(\frac{a}{2})-\sin^2(\frac{a}{2})=-\frac{\sin^2(a)}{4}$$
which by completing the square or by applying quadratic formula I got:-
$$\sin^2(\frac{a}{2})= \frac{1\pm \sqrt{1- \sin^2(a)}}{2}$$
or, $$\sin^2(\frac{a}{2})=\frac{1\pm \cos(a)}{2}$$ 
or, $$\sin(\frac{a}{2})=\pm \sqrt{\frac{1\pm \cos(a)}{2}}$$

Even though I haven’t broke the algebraic rules, I know there is some mistakes and that's what I'm trying to trace. Where is the problem actually? How's the 'minus' thing became 'plus-minus' thing?? Help me please.

Thanks in advance--

Comment: When you introduced $\sin^4(a/2)$ you also introduced a spurious solution for $\sin^2(a/2)$.

Comment: Can I know the reason, please??

Comment: @Paul Squaring an equation is not necessary reversible all the time. $a=b \implies a^2=b^2$ is true but $a^2=b^2\implies a=b$ is not necessary true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, it's better
$$\left|\sin\frac{\alpha}{2}\right|=\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos\alpha}{2}}$$ and
$$\left|\cos\frac{\alpha}{2}\right|=\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos\alpha}{2}}$$

Your mistake is that $\sqrt{x^2}=\pm x$ is wrong.

The right identity it's:
$$\sqrt{x^2}=|x|.$$

For example,  after 
$$\sin^4\frac{\alpha}{2}-\sin^2\frac{\alpha}{2}+\frac{\sin^2\alpha}{4}=0$$ we obtain:
$$\sin^2\frac{\alpha}{2}=\frac{1+\sqrt{1-\sin^2\alpha}}{2}$$ or
$$\sin^2\frac{\alpha}{2}=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-\sin^2\alpha}}{2},$$ which is
$$\sin^2\frac{\alpha}{2}=\frac{1+|\cos\alpha|}{2}$$ or
$$\sin^2\frac{\alpha}{2}=\frac{1-|\cos\alpha|}{2},$$ which is
$$\sin^2\frac{\alpha}{2}=\frac{1+\cos\alpha}{2}$$ or
$$\sin^2\frac{\alpha}{2}=\frac{1-\cos\alpha}{2},$$ which 
 does not give a mistake, but also, does not give any sense.

Also, squaring of the both sides in $\sin\alpha=2\sin\frac{\alpha}{2}\cos\frac{\alpha}{2}$ gave a wrong case.

Because $a=b$ is not equivalent to $a^2=b^2.$

Comment: No,no,no, I asked for finding my mistake, not for correcting it. As I know the correct formula already

Comment: @Paul See please better my post.

Comment: @Paul I added something. See now.

Comment: Then It's going to be worse than me. See: $\frac {1\pm \sqrt{1- \sin(a)^2}$ or, $...\sqrt{(\pm\sqrt{1-\sin(a)})^2}$ or, $\sqrt{\cos(a)^2}$ or $+\cos(a)$. Look it’s plus and not minus, which is even worse as the sign is totally reversed resulting r.h.s of cosine's half angle formula

Comment: then what should I do. How to manage to derive it from sine's formula

Comment: @Paul It's "or"! One of these formulas is true. Also, use $\sin^2\frac{\alpha}{2}=1-\cos^2\frac{\alpha}{2}$ and you don't get any contradiction.

Comment: Yeah I know I've use the correct formula. But it’s knid of curiousment. I mean how to proof(mathematicall) that other equation is wrong

Comment: @Paul Your attempt say, that your way does not give a needed formula. It is better to use $\sin^2\frac{\alpha}{2}=\frac{1-\cos\alpha}{2}.$

Comment: you mean I shouldn’t try to derive from sin2a formula

Comment: @Paul You need to consider two cases: $\cos\alpha\geq0$ and $\cos\alpha<0$. Yes, I think so. It's just very ugly and it's not necessary.

Comment: oh, oh, oh, okey. Now I can understand. That's why there is abs and what it say is use the equation which better suit yours depending on my(it's value.

Comment: @Paul I wrote it better. See now.

Comment: Where??!! Nothing's changed

Comment: @Paul I deleted the absolute value sign.

Comment: And how is a=b is not equivalent to a^2=b^2. This is a identity we have been taught from the first day of algebra.

Comment: And what's the mistake or unmathematical thing to square botth sides

Comment: @Paul Squaring of both sides it's not equivalent step. For example: $-2=2$ is wrong, but $(-2)^2=2^2$ is true. We see that you understood something not right. $a^2=b^2$ gives $a^2-b^2=0$ or $(a-b)(a+b)=0,$ which gives $a=b$ or $a=-b$.

Comment: Oooh, I got it.